# How to convert SQL with CAST function to Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with this sql.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_date > '2017-04-20 23:59:59'
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'views'
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This query return most viewed posts. I want to convert it to Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` modal as said in [this tutorial](http://www.webhat.in/article/wordpress-tutorials/accessing-wordpress-post-through-laravel/) then below query will do the thing for you.

```
$dp = DB::getTablePrefix();
$order_by = "CAST(" . $dp . "postmeta.meta_value AS unsigned) DESC";
BlogPost::with('postmetas')
    ->where('posts.post_date', '>', '2017-04-20 23:59:59')
    ->where('postmeta.meta_key', 'views')
    ->orderByRaw($order_by)
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps!